# Language capabilities and language abilities?

Tags: word-choice

Using [Google trends](https://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=language%20capabilities%2C%20language%20abilities&cmpt=q), it seems that language abilities is much more popular than language capabilities. Do they have the same meaning? And which one of abilities and capabilities could go in the blank?

> As a bilingual, he utilized his Chinese and English language _________ to guide English tourists in China.

Comment: I would use *abilities*, which shows that the answers you get will largely be based on opinion. In addition, for questions about word meanings, we ask the user to consult online dictionaries and ask a question here if they have difficulty understanding a specific meaning as used in a specific context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Language skills" would fit better in your example. "Language abilities" is acceptable. "Language capabilities" sounds like someone trying to choose a longer word to sound more educated than they are.

Skills is used specifically for things learned by practice or experience (like languages), while abilities and capabilities can be used for either learned or innate potential. It's hard to explain the difference between ability and capability, but ability is used more for physical talents and capability is used more for psychological capacity (for example, *is he capable of murder?*).